# what is Delegate and when to use it?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, delegates

i have searched on the Google but could not find exactly what the delegate is and when to use delegate? can any one explain me with an example?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx. You definitely didn't Google hard enough.

Comment: [Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) explains it for you.

Comment: +1 As no reason to downvote this question, and if so then please comment the downvote.

Comment: The number one Google result for "C# delegate" is an MSDN page answering these questions pretty well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=VS.80%29.aspx Which bit don't you understand?

Comment: @O.D.: Since the downvote tooltip has recently been amended to include "This question does not show any research effort", it appears to me that Rafe's comment is perfectly sufficient explanation for any downvotes.

Comment: i searched on google but something was unclear in my mind that is why asked this question...now it's all clear now by **this-Me** 's post.....thanks...

Comment: Also the Related list contains a few close matches to the title question, and I know there are dozens of dupes on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it cleared here :

What :
http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx

when :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301810.aspx

Comment: thnx ..it's all cleared with delegate now

Answer (score 2):

A delegate is kind of like a callback, but it allows you to register more than one callback action.

Maybe an example is easier: you have an OnClick delegate. By default, nothing happens. But you can register 1, or 2, or N callbacks which will ALL receive the OnClick event.

Answer (score 1):

Delegate is a concept related to Delegation Design Pattern. Let me point you to the wiki link so you can take over the study from there.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

Comment: thnx shaunak it's all cleared with delegate now..

Answer (score 1):

In simplest terms, a delegate is just like a function assigned to a variable (I'm not sure if that's really what happens under the hood but it helps to think of it like that). If you have programmed in C++, its like the address of a function or the return value of GetProcAddress() but with more functionality and typesafety.

You can call the delegate like regular function, pass it as a function argument (like a regular variable) and it can also be null. Google it again (or visit the links of other posters), there are lots of materials about delegates.